# Custom agendaWeek Title

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to add the weeknumber in front of the title of the agendaWeek view. It should be like: "W07, February 9 — 15".

I tried:

```
views: {
    week: {
        titleFormat: '[W]W[,] MMMM D' 
}
```

but the result is: "W7, February 9 — 7, February 15"

Is there a simple way to get the format I need?

Comment: Can you add the line(s) of code you are using to format the date? I'm just having a hard time seeing how '[W]W[,] MMMM D' results in "W7, February 9 — 7, February 15". Also, check out moment.js docs if you haven't yet: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I formated the code. It's very strange because even if the titleFormat is 'W' only, the result is:   '7 — 7'